# What will be the output of following snippet? And why?

Tags: c

what will be the output of the following snippet and why?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void main(){
printf("Before while");
while(1);
printf("After while");
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Why don't you give it a try and find out what happens? Consider using a debugger.

Comment: @Twonky: Running a program can only tell you what one C implementation does. It cannot tell you all the possibilities that the C standard permits or requires.

Answer (score 3):

If you had just taken the effort to compile and run, you probably would have seen nothing.

That's because:

1. Even though you're printing `Before while`, you do not send a newline character at the end. Since standard output is generally line buffered for an interactive device<sup>(a)</sup>, it should cache this until you send a newline, flush the stream, or exit the program.
2. You do *none* of those things because `while(1);` (note the semicolon) is an infinite loop that does nothing in its body, meaning it will never reach the second `printf`.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> If you're interested in this behaviour, there are basically three buffering strategies for output.

- Unbuffered means output is passed straight through;
- Line-buffered means output is cached until a newline is output (although it may also be output *without* a newline if, for example, the buffer fills up);
- Fully-buffered means output is cached until the buffer is full at which point it's output and the buffer starts afresh.

The rules in the ISO C standard (`C11 7.21.3 Files /7`) for the three standard streams are:

> At program startup, three text streams are predefined and need not be opened explicitly - standard input (for reading conventional input), standard output (for writing conventional output), and standard error (for writing diagnostic output).
>
> As initially opened, the standard error stream is not fully buffered; the standard input and standard output streams are fully buffered if and only if the stream can be determined not to refer to an interactive device.

Comment: Thank you for your response, i know it was a silly question. I tried it running and i found nothing so i was worried why this is so. I didn't got this "Since standard output is line buffered if it can be ascertained to be an interactive device". Can you please explain it a bit more.

Comment: @dipeshpatidar, added a footnote to explain further.